# How could I make several disks as one so that I could have one disk with space

Tags: ubuntu, partition, lvm, hard-disk, disk

Initially, I had an 200Gb disk (/dev/sda) where are located

- boot loader (/disk/sda1)
- OS itself   (/disk/sda2)

Then via VMware it was added several disks

- /dev/sdb (150 Gb)
- /dev/sdc (1 TB)

Now it looks like that
[image]
[image]

The deal is /dev/sda is almost full. And my tries to create united disk via lvm caused errors. Actually it is impossible to perform **pvcreate** on **/dev/sda** as it is root.

How could I make these three disks one so that I could have one disk with space? (200Gb+150Gg+1000Gg)

I do not have experience in unix administration, so I would appreciate your help and suggestions.

With regards

Comment: wow already got minus two! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your only original disk `sda` contains just one Linux partition and is not already using LVM, it is going to be somewhat laborious to get to the configuration you want.

But since you have plenty of disk space available with your new disks (`sdb` and `sdc`), you could do it this way:

Step 1: Mount `/dev/sdc1` at `/mnt` or some other suitable temporary location, and backup all your existing data to it.

Step 2: Reinstall the OS on `sda`, being careful to let the installer make changes **only** to this disk. This time, tell the installer that you'll want a LVM-based disk layout. Such a layout may include a separate `/boot` filesystem (500M..1G should be plenty), as having a single root filesystem that extends to multiple disks may cause problems for bootloaders. Better safe than sorry.

Step 3: After the OS is reinstalled, your root filesystem should now be on a LVM logical volume. Use `pvcreate /dev/sdb` to initialize the whole disk as a LVM PV, and use `vgextend <name of your VG> /dev/sdb` to use it as an extension of your volume group, and then `lvextend -r -l 100%FREE <device name of your root LV>`. Now your root filesystem should be close to 350G in size, so you'll be able to restore your backup comfortably.

Step 4: Mount `/dev/sdc1` again to `/mnt` or similar temporary location, and restore your data. Make sure everything works.

Step 5: Unmount `/dev/sdc1`, run `pvcreate /dev/sdc`, `vgextend <name of your VG> /dev/sdc`, and then you can extend your root filesystem again: `lvextend -r -l 100%FREE <device name of your root LV>`

In the future: if you still need more space, you can ask the VMware administrator to just extend `sdb` (or `sdc`), and then do `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan` to detect the new size, `pvextend /dev/sdb` to make it usable for LVM, then `lvextend` again to make the new space usable for the filesystem. Since these disks are now all-LVM with no partition tables, you can easily on-line extend them.